# Вопрос по play kotlinlang org

Tags: kotlin

Захотелось мне поступить в интернатуру в одну компанию. И для этого нужно решить простую задачку, как мне показалось.

- компьютер загадывает число от 0 до 100
- я должен вводить числа. Компьютер сообщает больше, меньше или угадал.
- игра ведется в консоли в диалоговом режиме
- написать программу нужно на сайте https://play.kotlinlang.org
  Вот только этот сайт не поддерживает консольный ввод!!!!
  readLine() не работает, импорт сканера с java не работает
  Третий день ломаю голову, что же я делаю не так.
  может кто подскажет в каком направлении копать?

Comment: используйте `fun main(args: Array<String>)` и передавайте аргументы через пробел в Program arguments поле

Comment: мне нужно это делать циклично. а аргументы можно внести только один раз при запуске программы.
Если я гдето ошибся - можете посоветовать информацию которую нужно обработать?

Comment: можно ввести несколько аргументов через пробел, если всё равно не подходит, то тут уже стоит обратиться к тому, кто формировал задание

Comment: Этот сайт не поддерживает консольный ввод. Возможно в задании требуется написать код программы на этом сайте чтобы легче было его отправить оттуда на проверку и не подразумевает что он там будет выполняться.